# Setting a target temperature throwing an error in Nest thermostat

Tags: nest-api

Setting target temperature throwing an error like below. I am using php curl to set the temperature. Any help is appreciated.

```
object(stdClass)#72 (2) {
    ["cmd"]=>
           string(12) "REINIT_STATE"
     ["pod"]=>
           string(5) "rts04"
}
```

Code:

```
echo "Setting target temperature...\n";
$success = $nest->setTargetTemperature(150,$device_serial_number);
var_dump($success);

//***********************//
 public function setTargetTemperature($temperature, $serial_number) {
        $serial_number = $this->getDefaultSerial($serial_number);
        $temperature = $this->temperatureInCelsius($temperature, $serial_number);
        echo $temperature;
        $data = json_encode(array('target_change_pending' => TRUE, 'target_temperature' => $temperature));
        return $this->doPOST("/v2/put/shared." . $serial_number, $data);
    }

//************//
 private function doPOST($url, $data_fields) {
        return $this->doRequest('POST', $url, $data_fields);
    }

    private function doRequest($method, $url, $data_fields, $with_retry=TRUE) {


        $ch = curl_init();
        if ($url[0] == '/') {
            $url = $this->transport_url . $url;
        }
        $headers = array('X-nl-protocol-version: ' . self::protocol_version);
        if (isset($this->userid)) {
            $headers[] = 'X-nl-user-id: ' . $this->userid;
            $headers[] = 'Authorization: Basic ' . $this->access_token;
        }
        if (is_array($data_fields)) {
            $data = array();
            foreach($data_fields as $k => $v) {
                $data[] = "$k=" . urlencode($v);
            }
            $data = implode('&', $data);
        } else if (is_string($data_fields)) {
            $data = $data_fields;
        }
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, self::user_agent);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $this->cookie_file);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $this->cookie_file);
        if ($method == 'POST') {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
            $headers[] = 'Content-length: ' . strlen($data);
        }
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        if (DEBUG) {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, '127.0.0.1:8888');
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        } else {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, TRUE); // for security this should always be set to true.

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);    // for security this should always be set to 2.
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 1);        // Nest servers now require TLSv1; won't work with SSLv2 or even SSLv3!

            // Update cacert.pem (valid CA certificates list) from the cURL website once a month
            $curl_cainfo = sys_get_temp_dir() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'cacert.pem';
            $last_month = time()-30*24*60*60;
            if (!file_exists($curl_cainfo) || filemtime($curl_cainfo) < $last_month || filesize($curl_cainfo) < 100000) {
                file_put_contents($curl_cainfo, file_get_contents('http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem'));
            }
            if (file_exists($curl_cainfo) && filesize($curl_cainfo) > 100000) {
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $curl_cainfo);
            }
        }
        $response = curl_exec($ch);

        $info = curl_getinfo($ch);

        if ($info['http_code'] == 401 || (!$response && curl_errno($ch) != 0)) {
            if ($with_retry && $this->use_cache()) {
                // Received 401, and was using cached data; let's try to re-login and retry.
                @unlink($this->cookie_file);
                @unlink($this->cache_file);
                if ($info['http_code'] == 401) {
                    $this->login();
                }
                return $this->doRequest($method, $url, $data_fields, !$with_retry);
            } else {
                throw new RuntimeException("Error: HTTP request to $url returned an error: " . curl_error($ch), curl_errno($ch));
            }
        }

        $json = json_decode($response);
        if (!is_object($json) && ($method == 'GET' || $url == self::login_url)) {
            if (strpos($response, "currently performing maintenance on your Nest account") !== FALSE) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Error: Account is under maintenance; API temporarily unavailable.", NESTAPI_ERROR_UNDER_MAINTENANCE);
            }
            if (empty($response)) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Error: Received empty response from request to $url.", NESTAPI_ERROR_EMPTY_RESPONSE);
            }
            throw new RuntimeException("Error: Response from request to $url is not valid JSON data. Response: " . str_replace(array("\n","\r"), '', $response), NESTAPI_ERROR_NOT_JSON_RESPONSE);


  }

        if ($info['http_code'] == 400) {
            if (!is_object($json)) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Error: HTTP 400 from request to $url. Response: " . str_replace(array("\n","\r"), '', $response), NESTAPI_ERROR_API_OTHER_ERROR);
            }
            throw new RuntimeException("Error: HTTP 400 from request to $url. JSON error: $json->error - $json->error_description", NESTAPI_ERROR_API_JSON_ERROR);
        }

        // No body returned; return a boolean value that confirms a 200 OK was returned.
        if ($info['download_content_length'] == 0) {
            return $info['http_code'] == 200;
        }

        return $json;
    }
```

doPOST function called from setTargetTemperature. doRequest function called from doPOST.

For more reference see here https://github.com/gboudreau/nest-api

Answer (score 0):

the easy things are:

Make sure the thermostat is in heat/cool mode, or cool mode.
Make sure the thermostat is not set to away.

Can you post the code block you are using to make the call?

Comment: I made changes as per your answer still getting same result. Yes i will add code block to above question.

Comment: Ah bingo, that's the unofficial API. You should checkout developer.nest.com to use the official API.